# Database Mail Profile empty for user

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2016 with Database Mail enabled. The database admin can send test emails successfully. But when I log in with my account, and try to send test email from Management->Database Mail, the Database Mail Profile drop-down box is empty. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: You sure you are on the same server? does it also fail with `exec sp_send_dbmail`?

Comment: yes, I verified that I am on the same server. It also fails with exec sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: I don't see how the test email would work for him. When he goes into the DB mail setting, is it populated?

Comment: Yes, it's populated. I was told my account has been granted execute permissions on sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: That just means you can use that proc, not that you would be able to change the config. Smells like a security issue but i can't find any documentation on the minimaly required server level access.